# Resizing windows to a particular width and height instantly

Tags: window-manager

For some reason, I wish to resize a window to a very large size, 4-5 times larger than my screen size. For now, I am doing it manually by moving the entire window but one corner out of the screen and then pulling the corner to expand the window. However, this is very time taking. Is there some way to resize the window to a particular height and width instantly ? (perhaps from commandline or with the help of some small app or something else)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I propose two solutions

#### wmctrl

Install the `wmctrl` package, then you can resize your window with

```
wmctrl -r string -e 0,left,up,width,height
```

where `string` is a substring of the window's title, `(left,up)` are the desired screen coordinates of the upper left window's corner, and `(width,height)` are the desired window's dimensions.

For a more precise window's choice, run `wmctrl -l`, which will give you a list of records containing window's ID, screen's number and window's title. Then you can resize a particular window by ID with

```
wmctrl -i -r ID -e 0,left,up,width,height
```

More information in [`wmctrl`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/en/man1/wmctrl.1.html) man page.

#### devilspie

Install the package `devilspie`, then create the folder `~/.devilspie` and a file `my-name.ds` in this folder, with content:

```
(if (is (window_name) "My Window") (geometry "widthxheight+left+up"))
```

then execute `devilspie` to resize your window.

Comment: Thank you! I slight problem - if I resize the window to a large size, the window manager (i think compiz) gets killed and another window manager with very basic windowing capabilities comes in. Any way to avoid this?

Comment: From `wmctrl` man page: "`wmctrl` is a command that can be used to interact with an X Window manager that is compatible with the EWMH/NetWM specification." Probably `compiz` is not fully compatible or has some bugs, and I cannot help with that.

Comment: @Guanidene: I proposed an alternative solution.

Comment: You may also want to use `-r :ACTIVE` to get the current focused window. I added this to a shortcut to move my windows to the right position instantly, whichever ones I had focus on.

Comment: A minor correction to the previous comment: it is `-r :ACTIVE:` (an additional colon is needed at the end).

Comment: You can use `wmctrl -l` to get a list of values to pass `-r`. Window title with spaces can be put in double-quotes.

Comment: One big advantage of `wmctrl` over some other tools that it allows setting a window size bigger than the physical screen.  e.g. `wmctrl -r 'TITLE' -e 0,-2176,-3496,8192,8192` to resize to a window to 8192×8192 and center it on a (physical) 3840×1200 screen.