# How to resize windows exactly in XFCE?

Tags: xfce, window, resize

I was wondering if, in XFCE (my laptop is older and Unity is slow) it is possible to resize windows to exact pixel amounts?

e.g. Let's say I want a 501x504px window. Is this possible? Even if the command line is needed.

I need exact sizes for some training videos where I want to capture some windows.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

From UbuntuForums.org:

> #### Re: How to precisely resize windows in XFCE?
>
> `xdotool` will allow you to resize windows on the fly. For example, to resize an existing Mousepad window to 400x400 pixels:
>
> ```sh
> xdotool windowsize $(xdotool search --name "Mousepad" | tail -1) 400 400
> ```
>
> If you want to start a program with a specific size, you can use the `--geometry` or `-g` parameters if the application supports them, or use a tool like `devilspie`.

Running the `xdotool` command worked perfectly. I just substituted `Mousepad` with whatever the name of the application was.

---

If you want to select the target window interactively, you can combine the two `xdotool` window commands `windowsize` and `selectwindow`:

```sh
xdotool selectwindow windowsize 800 600
```

Answer (score 2):

In the past, I've used wmctrl to achieve this. The only downside is you have to use the command line to make changes. The old article I used to reference is broken, here is a new reference: [Resizing windows to a particular width and height instantly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94859/resizing-windows-to-a-particular-width-and-height-instantly)

Comment: The link is broken...